# How to generate user profile route with Angular2 + Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase

I am having trouble finding resources that might explain how to develop a custom user page route. Something like a `www.website.com/user/uid`, where `uid` represents the user's ID set by Firebase.

So for a sample like:

```
const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent }
];
```

How might I create a user profile page and its route?

Any insights and/or resources would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'profile/:id', component: ProfileComponent }
];
```

Then in your ProfileComponent

```
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
```

and your constructor:

```
constructor(private _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
  _activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
    this.id = parseInt(params['id']);
  });
}
```